# How to check if background data is enabled on the android?

Tags: android

I want to check if the user enabled background data on his/her device and display a message if it is disabled.

How can I check if it has been enabled?
I tried

```
import android.provider.Settings;

//...
Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.BACKGROUND_DATA);
//and
Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.BACKGROUND_DATA);
```

But they are returning null.

Thank you,
Achie.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to use the [Connectivity Manager](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) to get this info.

```
ConnectivityManager mgr = (ConnectivityManager)Context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
boolean bgData = mgr.getBackgroundDataSetting();
```

Comment: Just a word of caution, this does not work as of ICS. In ICS this method will always return true. For the correct use in ICS see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getBackgroundDataSetting()

Comment: It's better to wrap it in `ConnectivityManagerCompat.getRestrictBackgroundStatus(mgr)`