# Test if background data and packet data is enabled or not

Tags: android, networking

I wish to detect if a user has enabled both background data (settings->accounts and sync->background data) and packet data (settings->wireless and network->mobile networks->use packet data) so I can inform the user how to enable them.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494483/how-to-check-if-background-data-is-enabled-on-the-android) says how to test the background data but it has been deprecated. The recommendation says to use getActiveNetworkInfo() but this might return the WIFI connection and therefore not display if background data is enabled or not.

I have not found any links on how to detect if packet data is enabled or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this exact same question and I had to start a bounty to get the answer. Cost me a third of my reputation, but well worth it.

```
boolean mobileDataEnabled = false; // Assume disabled
        ConnectivityManager cm1 = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        try {
            Class cmClass = Class.forName(cm1.getClass().getName());
            Method method = cmClass.getDeclaredMethod("getMobileDataEnabled");
            method.setAccessible(true); // Make the method callable
            // get the setting for "mobile data"
            mobileDataEnabled = (Boolean)method.invoke(cm1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Some problem accessible private API
            // TODO do whatever error handling you want here
        }
```

As I say, I cant claim credit for know this, my question was answered by https://stackoverflow.com/users/769265/david-wasser

but it cost me, so if you want to accept this as an answer I can start to get me some of my reputation points back! :)

Comment: Thanks! That answered one part of my question. In the meantime I have upgraded to Jelly Bean and here google has removed the background data from the sync menu :-/ Anyway - I accepted your answer since it solves my problem on JB.

Comment: ahh, right, I did not realise that packet data and sync data were different settings. I presumed it was two different ways of saying the same thing. It seems like it may be possible to check this using the same method as above. I'll check it out and get back to you if I work it out!

Comment: I came across this answer which seems to answer the other part of your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996327/how-to-enable-the-background-data-settings-in-android

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Weird I did not find that when I searched :-)